# Link static web app's preview deployment to Azure Function's non-default deployment slot using az cli

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-static-web-app

Using this command:

```
az staticwebapp functions link --function-resource-id "/subscriptions/[sub-id]/resourceGroups/[resource-group-name]/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/[func-name]/slots/[slot-name]" -n [swa-name] -g [swa-rg-name] --environment-name "[env-name]" --force
```

I get error:

```
ERROR: --function-resource-id must specify a function resource ID. To get resource ID, use the following commmand, inserting the function group/name as needed: 
az functionapp show --resource-group "[FUNCTION_RESOURCE_GROUP]" --name "[FUNCTION_NAME]" --query id
```

How do I specify the Azure Function deployment slot?

Comment: not sure if supported. is it possible to do that through the portal ?

Comment: maybe linking a backend would do the trick ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/staticwebapp/backends?view=azure-cli-latest#az-staticwebapp-backends-link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the generic `az staticwebapp backends link` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/staticwebapp/backends?view=azure-cli-latest#az-staticwebapp-backends-link). It should accept any valid resourceId

```
az staticwebapp backends link `
  --backend-resource-id <function app slot resource id>`
  --name <static website name>`
  --resource-group <resource group name>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the resource id place you have to keep resource id of function app as below:

```
$x=az functionapp show --resource-group "rbojja" --name "rith8976" --query id
```

Then you can use below command:

```
az staticwebapp functions link --function-resource-id $x -n "rith98webapp" -g "rbojja" --environment-name "rith8976-rithwik" --force
```

You can also use backend command as @Thomas mentioned :

```
az staticwebapp backends link -n rith98webapp -g "rg" --backend-resource-id $x --backend-region "East US"
```

[image]